# htaccess rewrite forcing https works on some parts of site but not others

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to force https on certain pages and subdirectories of the site, however it only works for subdirectories, not pages.

This is my current htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}  off
RewriteRule ^/?admin/ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^/checkout.php https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,QSA]
```

The first rewrite works, but the second one doesn't. So if I navigate to www.domain.com/admin/ it will redirect to https://domain.com/admin/ but if I navigate to www.domain.com/en/checkout.php it doesn't redirect to the https version. Why is that? I remember using the same exact code only with a different page instead of checkout.php and it worked back then. I can't test it on that page because I don't have it anymore but I literally copy-pasted the rewrite rule and changed the name of the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**`The first rewrite works, but the second one doesn't.`**

Yes it won't because of these reasons:

1. RewriteCond is only applied to the immediate RewriteRule
2. RewriteRule doesn't match leading `/` in .htaccess (you have it optional in 1st rule)

Also both of rules can be combined by using OR. With those suggestions replace your code with this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^/?(admin/|en/checkout\.php) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks, but it still doesn't work for checkout.php. I'm not sure if the backslash you have after the word checkout is accidental - I tried both with and without it, doesn't work either way. Still works for admin/ though.

Comment: What is your full URL for checkout.php?

Comment: www.domain.com/en/checkout.php - and for admin it's www.domain.com/admin/ - could the /en/ be the cause of the problem somehow?

Comment: But I did, it's been in the question the whole time, you just missed it my friend:)